# Link 2 cells in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I want to link 2 cells in GridBagLayout.
I use Netbeans, so I write in JAppletForm.

```
JTextField dodawanyTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();

dodawanyTextField.setText(nazwaLekcjiTextField.getText());

gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;

jPanel3.add(dodawanyTextField, gridBagConstraints);
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Please clarify: what do you mean by "link 2 cells"? What do you mean by "it is not working"?

Comment: I mean that, new element (JTextField) should occupy two cells (widths), but it takes only one.

Comment: Why it's not working to your liking is impossible to answer w/o seeing how the whole grid of components is assembled in the GBL.  Without it, we'd just be guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your `GridBagConstraint's` `weightx` and `fill` such that the component expands along the x axis:

```
gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1;
gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
```